# How to extract raw text (including comments) from HTML page with beautifulsoup python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Lets say I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph <!-- and a comment --></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to extract the whole text of the `<p>` tag including `<!-- and a comment -->`. Using .get_text() returns only "This is a paragraph".

I want the whole raw text like this: `This is a paragraph <!-- and a comment -->`.

How can this be achieved with beautifulsoup4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`decode_contents()`](https://exceptionshub.com/beautifulsoup-innerhtml.html)([doc](https://tedboy.github.io/bs4_doc/generated/generated/bs4.BeautifulSoup.decode_contents.html)), i.e.:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph <!-- and a comment --></p>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
for para_tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(para_tag.decode_contents())
    # This is a paragraph <!-- and a comment -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the `p` tag and use the `text` attribute to get its text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for para_tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(para_tag.text)
```

**Edit**:

If you're looking for the comment inside the tag as well, you can use the `comment` import from `bs4`:

```
s = """
<html>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph <!-- and a comment --></p>
</body>
</html>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

for para_tag, comment in zip(soup.find_all('p'), soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))):
    if comment:
       print(para_tag.text, "<!--" + comment + "-->")
    else:
        print(para_tag.text)
```

Edit 2:

Using the [.decode_contents()](https://tedboy.github.io/bs4_doc/generated/generated/bs4.BeautifulSoup.decode_contents.html):

```
for para_tag, comment in soup.find_all('p'):
       print(para_tag.decode_contents())
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
This is a paragraph <!-- and a comment -->
```

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη noted and edited with the fix, thank you! ^^

Comment: Also a very useful answer but I think the one from Pedro Lobito is slightly cleaner

Comment: @DirtyBit I've removed my downvote now. you don't need to be in rush to answer a question. Just read carefully then post the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the `p` element and then because you have the comment part you should remove the `p` from the cast string

```
html = """
<html>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph <!-- and a comment --></p>
</body>
</html>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

object = BeautifulSoup(html)
for i in objectin.find_all('p'):
    print(str(i).replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', ''))
```

Answer (score -2):

Firstly define your `Jsoup` Library and call it where you wants then use this method to extract P tag from `HTML`

`pgTagExtract = find('p')`